# Google ndb and memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-data-api

I am working on a Google app engine application which uses the Python ndb datastore APIs.
Since I am trying to optimize the application I am wondering about caching data instead of querying the datastore as described in this link http://blog.initlabs.com/post/16359268329/how-i-reduced-google-app-engine-costs-by-75.

Anyway as far as I understand NDB already transparently uses memcache https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

I see a high amount of read operations and I can't see why as the data are not frequently changed.

is it pointless to explicitly use memcache when using ndb?

**Update**

Although I refresh the same page I always see something like this in the appstat

```
 @0ms memcache.Get real=6ms api=0ms cost=0 billed_ops=[]
 @7ms datastore_v3.Get real=12ms api=0ms cost=0 billed_ops=[]
 @22ms datastore_v3.RunQuery real=16ms api=0ms cost=0 billed_ops=[]
 @41ms datastore_v3.RunQuery real=12ms api=0ms cost=0 billed_ops=[]
 @92ms datastore_v3.RunQuery real=71ms api=0ms cost=0 billed_ops=[]
```

which makes me think the memcache.Get (first Row) failed. Am I right? how can it be?

Comment: how do you see the read ops? what is the response time of those?

Comment: I see the percentage. I am the only user by now and it reaches 10% in few hours. Anyway I am introducing AppStats to have a bettere measurement

Comment: Try doing some profiling with this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Comment: Fantastic! Can you share the code that provokes that log? is there any call to memcache that you explicitly make?

Comment: no I do not make any explitic call to memcache since I thought ndb was already using it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68288/discussion-between-rafael-barros-and-lowcoupling).

Comment: You need to catrgorize the types of transactions and then work out which will/can be cached by ndb and which one you need to do yourself. For instance queries are not cached.  Only gets are.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear on what you're asking, so let me rephrase your question just to be on the safe side :

you're asking why, if you put your data into memcache, can the memcache get fail?  Well it's probably because the memcache flushed by itself, as it can randomly do.

If you see that EVERY time, then maybe something is wrong indeed. But the way I see it you made a datastore get that wasn't present in the memcache at first.